# Increment int var every 10 iterations of loop

Tags: php

I'm building a long query of dummy data. I have a for loop running a few thousand times, in each loop, it adds a new row to a query, with the increment variable used for dummy file names, 1.png, 2.png etc. I also need to increment a separate foreign key id, but it needs to only be every 10 iterations of the loop. can anyone help? Thanks.

```
$var = '';
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $path = '/test' . $i . '.pdf';
    $mess = 'Test message '. substr(md5($i), 0, 10);
    $did = 0;//How to increment this var by 1 every 10 iterations?
    $var .= "INSERT INTO `message` (`design_id`, `path`, `message`) VALUES ('$did', '$path', '$mess');"."<br />";
}
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
$did = 0;
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $did += $i % 10 == 9;
}
```

The expression `$i % 10` starts from 0, increases up to 9 (10 - 1) and then "wraps around" indefinitely. `$did` is increased every time it evaluates to 9, which is every 10 iterations.

It's interesting to note that you can use *any* value in the range [0, 9] for the comparison and it will still increase `$did` at the same rate; the difference is when the *first* increase will happen. By choosing 9 increases happen on the 10th, 20th, etc iteration. If you chose 0 instead, increases would happen on the 1st, 11th, 21st, etc.

Finally, if this technique is new it might feel more comfortable to use extra parens, for example

```
$did += ($i % 10 == 9);
```

or even a standalone `if` statement.

Comment: Jon answered it better and quicker :)

Answer (score 26):

$i+=10

Example:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i+=10) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide and floor.

$did = floor(i / 10);

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '';
$did = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $path = '/test' . $i . '.pdf';
    $mess = 'Test message '. substr(md5($i), 0, 10);
    if((i % 10) == 0){
          $did++;
     }
    $var .= "INSERT INTO `message` (`design_id`, `path`, `message`) VALUES ('$did', '$path', '$mess');"."<br />";
}
echo $var;
```